# Running a Search Array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to search through an array of integers from the user input using a target value, in this case, is called 'searchArray'. Every time I run a dimension of 5, with values {1 5 9 7 3}, and searching through that array with a target value of 9, it prints out the right information of "Found value 9 at index 2, taking 3 checks! The value v was not found in the array!". I need the last part of value v not to print out. I feel that I am putting the correct ranges for the if else statements, but for some reason it's still printing out that is was not found in the array, even though it was.
[Example of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4awG.png)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

//similar to lab02, except we are searching values through the array
    int dimension;
    int counter = 0;

//ask size of array from user
    cout << "Enter the size of the array: " << endl ;
    cin >> dimension;

//check the validity of the dimension sizes
    if (dimension < 1 || dimension > 10 ) {
    cout << "ERROR: You entered an invalid value for the array size!";
    }

//ask the user to enter the values in array size given
    int searchArray;
    int arr[dimension];

    cout <<"Enter the numbers in the array, separated by a space and press enter: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
}

//ask the user to enter the integer to search through array
     cout << "Please enter the key to search in the array: ";
     cin >> searchArray;

//use for loop to iterate through array while checking searchArray
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
    counter = counter + 1;

    if (searchArray == arr[i]) {
        cout << "Found value " << searchArray << " at index " << i << ", taking " << counter << " checks !";

    }     
    if (counter == 1 && searchArray == arr[i]) {
        cout << "We ran into the best case scenario! " << endl;
    break;

}   else if (counter == dimension && searchArray == arr[i]) {
        cout << "We ran into the worst-case scenario!" << endl; 
    break;

}   
    else if (counter == dimension && searchArray != arr[i]) { 
        cout << "The value v was not found in the array!" << endl;
    break;      

}
}
}
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, please.

Comment: For the 3 cases (best, worst, not found) you have an output and you do a `break`, but for the remaining  `found` cases (that are not best or worst) you do not exit the loop, so you continue searching.

Comment: You need to **debug** your code by putting a breakpoint in the `if` condition that you feel should not be taking place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you might change your if condition because you already test one time your `searchArray == arr[i]`

```
if (searchArray == arr[i]) {
    cout << "Found value " << searchArray << " at index " << i << ", taking " << counter << " checks !";
    if (counter == 1) {
       cout << "We ran into the best case scenario! " << endl;
    }else if(counter == dimension) {
        cout << "We ran into the worst-case scenario!" << endl; 
    }   
}
```

For checking if you found the value or not, I will probably use a boolean

```
find = false;    

for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
   counter = counter + 1;

   if (searchArray == arr[i]) {
       cout << "Found value " << searchArray << " at index " << i << ", taking " << counter << " checks !";
       find = true;
       if (counter == 1) {
           cout << "We ran into the best case scenario! " << endl;
       }else if(counter == dimension) {
           cout << "We ran into the worst-case scenario!" << endl; 
       }   
   } 
}
if (!find){
    cout << "The value v was not found in the array!" << endl;
}
```